# Django - Twitter URLs with hash bangs get broken when escaped

Tags: django

Django  escapes Twitter URLS in a way that Twitter doesn't like:
for example http://twitter.com/#!/bugspy becomes http://twitter.com/#%21%2Fbugspy

And twitter won't serve it.
How this can be fixed (without explicitly in the code replacing the %21%2F with !/) ?

Comment: Where exactly it esscape urls? In templates using urlencode filter? If so in django 1.3 there can be provided a list of non escaped characters e.g {{ value|urlencode:"#!" }}

Comment: In urlize template tag for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of django are you using? In django 1.3 it works fine.

```
>>> from django.template.defaultfilters import urlize
>>> urlize('http://twitter.com/#!/bugspy')
u'<a href="http://twitter.com/#%21/bugspy" rel="nofollow">http://twitter.com/#!/bugspy</a> '
```

And this url work fine on twitter.
Also you can look at this snipept : http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1445/

Comment: Strange, I use 1.3. (But directly in the template  ( e.g. some_url|urlize))

Comment: Just tried from template. Same result. {{ 'http://twitter.com/#!/bugspy'|urlize }} -  <a href="http://twitter.com/#%21/bugspy" rel="nofollow">http://twitter.com/#!/bugspy</a> . So it`s something else that corrupts your url.